# React: how to use inline styling while mapping through a render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically use the item's id while mapping through my items array in my Render().  How can I do this from within the render mapping I already have?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>New Houte</h1>
        {this.state.items.map(item => 
            <div className="item-container" key={item.id}>
              <div style={ { backgroundImage: 'url("../../images/' +{item.id} + ')' } } className="image-container" key="image">
```

Comment: You just did. This way is the good way. You're missing a quote though. And maybe an extension? Like `'url("../../images/' +{item.id} + '.png")'`

Comment: I keep getting a syntax error stating : `"Unexpected token, expecting ," and it's pointing to the period in {item.id} .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do:

```
<div style={ { backgroundImage: 'url("../../images/' +{item.id} + ')' } } className="image-container" key="image">
```

But do:

```
<div style={ { backgroundImage: 'url("../../images/' + item.id + '")' } } className="image-container" key="image">
```

or:

```
<div style={ { backgroundImage: `url("../../images/${item.id}")` } } className="image-container" key="image">
```

You open braces {} inside JSX to evaluate. Here, you're just inside a string, so it's raw JS and that's why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

In your case, it would be like this using backtick(the key left of number 1)

```
`{ { backgroundImage: `url("../../images/${item.id}")` } }`.
```